# I would like to instantiate modules based on selection, how?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I would like to instantiate some modules based on inputs, the reason behind is to be flexible in different test case run but with same set up.

For example, I have a module named checker.sv

```
If a variable/string = number/"text",
    `include "check_a"
else
    `inclcude "check_b"
```

where check_a and check_b basically a list of checker.sv instantiations like this :

```
checka file is :
checker icheck1 (sig1, sig2, 3.0)
checker icheck1 (sig1, sig2, 2.5)
            :
            :

checkb file is :
checker icheck1 (sig1, sig2, 3.9)
checker icheck1 (sig1, sig2, 1.5)
            :
            :
```

What is the best way to do this? I dont want to have all checkers on, I want to run my testbench with only the checkers I want for the particular run.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Deciding  what file to include is a compile time operation. Deciding which modules to instantiate is an elaboration time operation. This means you can't use variables. If you want to go down the include way, you can use the preprocessor:

```
`ifdef CHECK_A
    `include "check_a.svh"
`else
    `include "check_b.svh"
`endif
```

From your run script you have to either define `CHECK_A` or not. This depends on the simulator you're using, but most often it's done using a `-D` option or a `+define+`. Ex: `some_sim -D CHECK_A` will include `check_a.svh`, while omitting the define will cause the other checks to be instantiated.